# What serializer is used in RDLC reports?

Tags: c#, serialization, reporting-services

I have learned the hard way that if your objects cannot be correctly serialized then RDLC report generation does not work, and unfortunately it tends to fail in ways and with messages that have absolutely nothing to do with your object or properties that cannot serialize/deserialize.

Thus, before RDLC report generation I test the objects to see that they can serialize properly - and this gives an early exception message identifying exactly why the object does not serialize before trying to generate the report.

That works great - except I have not quite worked out which serializer to test with. I have tried BinaryFormatter, XmlSerializer, ObjectStateFormatter. Each of these fail to serialize some of my objects which nevertheless seem to work successfully when passed to an RDLC report. i.e. my testing is sometimes incorrectly identifying an object that cannot be used in an RDLC report, when in fact it can.

Therefore - does anybody know exactly how objects are serialized with RDLC reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the code in `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll` and it seems that it has custom code for serializing objects to XML, but then uses the `XML Serializer` in `System.Xml.dll` to serialize child objects that aren't primitives, arrays, or structs (like custom classes).  So it seems to use a combination of its own custom serialization and the XML serializer.

It would probably be best to assume your root object can serialize as long as all custom child objects (referenced via properties) can be processed by the XML serializer.

Comment: Thanks for that! You have also prompted me to install a disassembler (JetBrains dotPeek) so now I have a new toy in my toolbox to play with (as I could not find ReportViewer on referencesource.microsoft.com)

Comment: Not familiar with that one.  I used Telerik JustDecompile (free download) and just pointed it to the Report Viewer assembly.